# How to pass bool from one function to another?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain, mist

I want two functions to be checked true or false in one contract, that is, I get true in the calculations and want something. The code below shows my idea, but it does not work, I do not know why.

```
function transfer_money(uint _Number) pure public returns (bool){
    //code
    return true;
}

function transfer_property(bool) private {

    InfoProperty storage Transfer_Property = propertys[num];

    if (transfer_money()){
       //code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reflects a very basic lack of programming-concepts knowledge, which is not specifically related to Ethereum or to the given programming language (Solidity).

Comment: Thank you, I did not immediately understand what you were talking about, fixed it. 
It became a little embarrassing, but I still study, not so long ago I switched to practice.

Comment: OK, you're very much welcome. Good luck with studying and practicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `transfer_money` takes one input parameter.

So you cannot call `transfer_money()` without passing it.

Comment: And how to pass the parameter?

Comment: @GumanXD: Inside the `()`. I think you should probably start with the basics of programming.

Comment: I understand this, but he will throw an error when I try to do it. He says to do this either through another contract or through a struct. Mist says that it is not declared globally, and if I declare it, then he complains that I do not use contract or struct. " Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bool to uint256 requested. if (transfer_money(access)){"

Comment: @GumanXD: "Mist says that it is not declared globally" - are you trying to call `transfer_money` from outside the contract??? If yes, then: 1. You should mention this as part of your question, and demonstrate how exactly you are doing it. 2. You need to declare this function `public`.

Comment: @GumanXD: And the compilation error implies that the type of `access` is `bool`, while function `transfer_money` expect an input parameter of type `uint256`.

Comment: I try to call it inside the contract.

Comment: @GumanXD: So what does "Mist says that it is not declared globally" mean??? You couldn't have possibly gotten this error without calling one of your functions from Mist, which is **outside the contract** of course!

Comment: I do not know why he expects in uint256 condition. When I tried to fix the code, Mist told me something about this.

Comment: @GumanXD: You declared `function transfer_money(uint _Number)`, so the compiler expects that whenever you call this function, you pass an input parameter of type `uint` (which is an alias to type `uint256`). The compilation error, however, implies that you are passing an input parameter of type `bool`. Like I said at the beginning, I think you have some very basic programming concepts that you should study before starting to code.